# More efficient cookie cutter for boolean array to simulate detector response?

Tags: python, numpy, filter, vectorization

I am applying a predefined pattern to a chain of events to simulate a dead time of a detector.

I tried to think of a vectorized method to apply that pattern (e.g. [convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve)), but failed to find a suitable algorithm. The iterative approach works, but is rather slow (the simulator has to deal with millions of events).

Can you think of a vectorized method to get the same functionality as my `for loop` approach?

[image]

You can test the expected behavior with the attached pytests.

```py
import numpy as np


def detector_response(events: np.array, dead_time: int) -> np.array:
    """Iterate over events-array and apply dead_time to each event."""
    i = 0
    while i < len(events):
        if events[i]:
            events[i + 1 : i + dead_time + 1] = 0
            i += dead_time
        i += 1
    return events


def test_continuous_event_chain_get_spaced_by_deadtime():
    n_events = 1_000_000
    events = np.ones(n_events)
    dead_time = 9
    events_with_deadtime = detector_response(events, dead_time)
    print(events_with_deadtime)
    assert sum(events_with_deadtime) == n_events / (1 + dead_time)


def test_individual_events_remain_while_close_events_get_filtered():
    events = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
    dead_time = 3
    assert sum(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == 2


def test_concrete_pattern():
    events = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
    dead_time = 3
    expected_output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    assert (np.array(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == np.array(
        expected_output)).all()

    dead_time = 4
    expected_output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    assert (np.array(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == np.array(
        expected_output)).all()
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a concrete example of inputs and expected outputs to yours snippet? I'd like to know: A: does `events` only ever consist of ones and zeros? B: What is the goal of the slice in `pattern[:len(events)-i]`? C: Is `pattern` always  just ones (or maybe a binary vector, or could it contain arbitrary floats?)?

Comment: I will add a third test with a concrete result instead of just the sum. Regarding your questions: Yes, only 1s and 0s. The goal of `pattern[:len(events)-i]` is to prevent mismatch-errors when trying to put a dead-time-pattern at the very end of the event chain. And yes, the deadtime-pattern again is just binary 1s and 0s.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I get the hunch that it is not possible to vectorize, it looks like an inherently serial process (i.e. we have to process the array from start to finish, and we cannot independently process a given window, it always relies on the result of previous computations.) But of course I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: For the time being you can use a `while` loop (instead of `for`) and skip ahead to the end of each dead time block, no need to keep looping all those zeroes. And mostly a style note, but I'd define the pattern with `zeros` and only set the first value. It's fewer reassignments and can use system `calloc`.

Comment: thanks @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, skipping the inserted dead_times surely safes some time. I have updated my snipped accordingly. But unfortunatly not the factors I am looking for :)

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Do you have some idea about the expected sizes of `dead_time` as well as what the distribution of the gaps between the signal looks like? I was just thinking if the signals are very sparse it might be better to operate on the indices of the signals.

Comment: @flawr yes, the signals are rather sparse. I've tried to play around with event-index-differences (basically `np.diff(np.where(events)[0])`, but could not find a significantly faster and reliable algorithm for this format either.

Comment: Not sure where the data is coming from, but I'd say its probably from some simulation. Wouldn't it be easier to add dead time to that? I.e. do not introduce the event to the signal if there is a signal in the last `dead_time` seconds. Otherwise you end up with what you have, in some way double the computations, adding and then removing.

Comment: @AnderBiguri that would be right if that was the case, but this data is a measurement which then gets filtered by an adjustable dead time to neglect spurious events

Comment: @Christian ah I see. Not really an answer, but I think perhaps the software STIR may have an efficient implementation of that, maybe you can have a look.

Comment: You cannot vectorize this, as @flawr said, it’s a sequential process. But you could use Numba to speed this up by probably at least 100x.

Comment: Also, instead of `events[i: i + len(pattern)] = pattern[: len(events) - i]` do `events[i + 1: i + dead_time + 1] = 0`.

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks, fixed :) added a hyphen too, for good measure.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Haha, much better!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I applied @jit(nopython=False) to the original code (both the for- and the while-loop) (following https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html), which slowed down the execution by a factor of 3. Maybe I am doing something wrong...?

Comment: The first time you run the function it’ll be slower, it needs to compile the function. Subsequent times it should be two orders of magnitude faster. How are you timing the function?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @flawr's comment regarding scarcity, and with a lot of tinkering, I think I managed to make a vectorized version.

By calculating cumulative sums, which all reset on a valid event, this just might work - or my tests are not seeing the edge cases they need to see.

But the filtering got so complicated (especially that 139 character line in the middle still haunts me), that this approach has no speed bonus in my tests at all. So, if I cannot think of a simpler, more performant version, I will stick to the iterative approach for sake of simplicity.

```py
import numpy as np

def detector_response(events, dead_time):
    """Vectorized filtering based on event distance."""
    # extract event distance
    i_events = np.where(events)[0]
    delta = np.diff(i_events).astype(float)
    # identify events which are wide enough apart and hence "directly" valid
    delta_pad = np.concatenate(([dead_time+1], delta))  # first event is always valid
    directly_valid = delta_pad > dead_time
    delta_pad[directly_valid] = np.nan  # mask valid deltas with nan
    dead_time += 1
    # create "sawtooth ramp" which starts new from each nan
    delta[directly_valid[1:]] = 0
    delta_pad[np.isnan(delta_pad)] = np.concatenate(([0], np.diff(-np.cumsum(np.concatenate(([0, 0], delta[:-1])))[np.isnan(delta_pad)])))
    delta_ramp = np.cumsum(delta_pad)
    # identify dead_time crossovers in ramp
    dead_steps = np.diff(delta_ramp // dead_time) == 1
    dead_steps = np.concatenate(([False], dead_steps))
    delta_pad[dead_steps] = np.nan
    delta_pad[directly_valid] = np.nan
    filtered_events = np.zeros(events.shape)
    filtered_events[i_events[np.isnan(delta_pad)]] = 1
    return filtered_events.astype(int)


def test_continuous_event_chain_get_spaced_by_deadtime():
    n_events = 1_000_000
    events = np.ones(n_events)
    dead_time = 9
    events_with_deadtime = detector_response(events, dead_time)
    print(events_with_deadtime)
    assert sum(events_with_deadtime) == n_events / (1 + dead_time)


def test_individual_events_remain_while_close_events_get_filtered():
    events = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
    dead_time = 3
    assert sum(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == 2


def test_concrete_pattern():
    repetitions = 400
    events = np.tile(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]),repetitions)

    dead_time = 3
    expected_output = np.tile(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]), repetitions)
    assert (np.array(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == np.array(
        expected_output)).all()

    dead_time = 4
    expected_output = np.tile(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]), repetitions)
    assert (np.array(detector_response(events, dead_time)) == np.array(
        expected_output)).all()
```

Comment: Did you try using Numba with your original  code?

Comment: not yet, @CrisLuengo, I first want to explore purely numpy-ways of optimizing this code. But I will give numba a try after having explored other options, thanks!